# How to get the version number of the Advantage Database Server?

Tags: delphi, advantage-database-server

I can easily find out which client version I'm using, but how can I find out the server version?

There is a `AdsMgGetInstallInfo` ace function and a corresponding stored procedure `sp_mgGetInstallInfo`.

Do these require some special privileges?

I was expecting to find an `TAdsConnection.ServerVersion` property, but something like that doesn't seem to exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the [AdsConnection.ServerVersion](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage10.1/index.html?dotnet_adsconnection_serverversion.htm) only for the .NET provider, so it's probably missing in the Delphi Advantage Database wrapper.
But you might try to call the [Advantage Management API](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage10.1/index.html?ade_advantage_management_apis.htm) function [AdsMgGetInstallInfo](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage10.1/index.html?ade_adsmggetinstallinfo.htm) and to the [ADS_MGMT_INSTALL_INFO](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/advantage9.0/mergedProjects/ace/api4/ads_mgmt_install_info.htm) structure receive the `aucVersionStr` member where should be the Advantage Database Server version. So it might look like this (it's the modified example from the [AdsMgGetInstallInfo](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage10.1/index.html?ade_adsmggetinstallinfo.htm) reference).

Please note, I haven't tested it and I hope you will have all data types and structure definitions.

```
uses ACE;

function GetServerVersion: string;
var
  Size: UNSIGNED16;
  MgmtHandle: ADSHANDLE;
  ResultValue: UNSIGNED32;
  InstallInfo: ADS_MGMT_INSTALL_INFO;
begin
  Result := '';
  ResultValue := ACE.AdsMgConnect('\\MyExample\Server', nil, nil, @MgmtHandle);
  if (ResultValue <> AE_SUCCESS) then
    Exit;
  Size := SizeOf(ADS_MGMT_INSTALL_INFO);
  ResultValue := ACE.AdsMgGetInstallInfo(MgmtHandle, @InstallInfo, @Size);
  if (ResultValue <> AE_SUCCESS) then
    Exit;
  Result := InstallInfo.aucVersionStr;
end;
```

Comment: I took a look at the .NET assembly and they are using the Management API too, so this seems to be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You should call "sp_mgGetInstallInfo" store procedure.
Here is the Java example:

```
public static String getAdsVersion() throws ClassNotFoundException,
        SQLException {
    Connection conn = null;

    try {
        conn = getAdsConnection();
        CallableStatement statement = conn
                .prepareCall("{call sp_mgGetInstallInfo()}");
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
        resultSet.next();
        String version = resultSet.getString("Version");
        return version;
    } finally {
        if (conn != null) {
            conn.close();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using the [`sp_mgGetInstallInfo`](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/WebHelp/Advantage9.1/advantage_sql/system_procedures/procedures/sp_mggetinstallinfo.htm)  stored procedure method in Delphi, assuming you already have a TAdsQuery component with a valid connection available:

```
adsQuery.SQL.Clear();
adsQuery.SQL.Add('EXECUTE PROCEDURE sp_mgGetInstallInfo();');
adsQuery.Active := True;
versionStr := adsQuery.FieldByName('Version').AsString;
```